# Como pegar o conteúdo de outra tabela no Yii?

Tags: yii

Gostaria de no lugar do ID, exibir o nome do funcionário.

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'documento-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'id_documento',
        'nome_documento',
            array(
            'name'=>'Download',
            'header'=>'Download',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->path_documento, array("documento/download","id"=>$data->id_documento))',
            //'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'10%'),
        ),
        'id_documento_funcionario',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{delete}',
        ),
    ),
)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/721/view-a-related-field-in-cgridview/

```
'columns' => array(
    'funcionario.nome',
    // outras colunas...
),
```